# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' (finds another tag in the same spot fine but cant find the tag I need)

Tags: python, json, xml, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I have an xml file I am trying to extract information out of. Below is an excerpt of the file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Terms>
    <Term>
        <Title>.177 (4.5mm) Airgun</Title>
        <Description>The standard airgun calibre for international target shooting.</Description>
        <RelatedTerms>
            <Term>
                <Title>Shooting sport equipment</Title>
                <Relationship>Narrower Term</Relationship>
            </Term>
        </RelatedTerms>
    </Term>
    <Term>
        <Title>.22</Title>
        <Description>A rimfire calibre, much used in target shooting and often synonymous with the term smallbore.</Description>
        <RelatedTerms>
            <Term>
                <Title>Shooting sport equipment</Title>
                <Relationship>Narrower Term</Relationship>
            </Term>
        </RelatedTerms>
    </Term>
    <Term>
        <Title>.22 Long Rifle</Title>
        <Description>The standard .22 rimfire cartridge for target rifle and pistol use.</Description>
        <RelatedTerms>
            <Term>
                <Title>Shooting sport equipment</Title>
                <Relationship>Narrower Term</Relationship>
            </Term>
        </RelatedTerms>
    </Term>
    <Term>
        <Title>.22 Short</Title>
        <Description>Used as a target shooting round for timed fire pistol competitions.</Description>
        <RelatedTerms>
            <Term>
                <Title>Shooting sport equipment</Title>
                <Relationship>Narrower Term</Relationship>
            </Term>
        </RelatedTerms>
    </Term>
</Terms>
```

Below is the code I've written. If I comment out `"Title": rterm.find('Title').text,` the whole code runs and does exactly what it needs to do... however, I get *AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'* when I try run the code with that part in.

```
import json
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml_file = open('xml.xml', encoding='UTF-8') 
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_file, 'lxml-xml', from_encoding='UTF-8')

Terms = soup.select('Terms > Term')  
jsonObj = {"thesaurus": []} 


for term in Terms: 
    termDetail = { 
        "Description": term.find('Description').text, 
        "Title": term.find('Title').text extracted 
    }
    RelatedTerms = term.select('RelatedTerms > Term')
    if RelatedTerms:
        termDetail["RelatedTerms"] = []
        for rterm in RelatedTerms:
            termDetail["RelatedTerms"].append({
                "Title": rterm.find('Title').text,
                "Relationship": rterm.find('Relationship').text
            })
    jsonObj["thesaurus"].append(termDetail)

with open(r'D:\UNI\data_science\fit5196\assessment_1b\json.dat', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(jsonObj, json_file, indent = 3, sort_keys = True )
```

I really don't know why it is coming up with this error. there is text information in the text and it finds the *Relationship* tag fine. I'm at my wits end

Any and all advice is appreciated

Comment: Perhaps the title is a child of another element

Comment: how would you go about coding that in that section? when I just print out ```RelatedTerms``` it comes up with 
'''[<Term>
 <Title>Freestyle Skiing terms and techniques</Title>
 <Relationship>Narrower Term</Relationship>
 </Term>]''' 

so it knows that *Title* is in there.

Comment: ur goal is to get the Freestyle Skiing terms and techniques text ?

Comment: I ran your code as is and get the complete `jsonObj`, no `AttributeError`. I only removed the `from_encoding` argument as redundant, but that shouldn't make a difference for your problem. Also deleted "extracted" from `"Title": term.find('Title').text extracted` which is just a typo in the question I assume.